# PHP find values in Multi-Dimetional Array

Tags: php, arrays, find, contains

I am looking for dates that correspond with events, and hoping to return the name of the event. 
Here is a simple example using Birthdays.

```
function find_event( $month,$day ){

    $event = array(
        ["Sam","1","1"],
        ["Jim","2","3"],
        ["Sally","3","11"],
        ["Buck","4","4"],
        ["Ted","12","22"]
    ); // event name, month, day

    /* what code goes here? */

    return "Happy Birthday, ".$event[$key][0]."!";
}

find_event(12,22);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<?php
function find_event( $month,$day ){

    $event = array(
        ["Sam","1","1"],
        ["Jim","2","3"],
        ["Sally","3","11"],
        ["Buck","4","4"],
        ["Ted","12","22"]
    ); // event name, month, day

    foreach ($event as $e) {
        if($e[1] == $month && $e[2] == $day) {
            return "Happy Birthday, ". $e[0]."!";
        }
    }
    return null;
}

echo find_event(12,22);
```

Comment: I really like this. I have't tested it, but it looks right to me!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but it need to be work:

```
foreach ($event as $key => $e) {
    if ($e[1] == $month && $e[2] == $day) {
        $match = $key;
        break;
    }
}

if (!empty($match)) {
    return $event[$match][0];
}
```

Comment: Slick, looks like you and Alban are on the same track!

Comment: I didn't see that it's already answered, but yeah, that's the solution, but I edited it now, 'cause it wasn't proper enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

(skip to the bottom to skip explanation and get commented code with the "best" long-term solution)

Disclaimer: This stuff is not necessary for a small project... But as a learning exercise I recommend doing it.  It creates much more stable, flexible, readable code in the long run. Not to mention if you get a job as a programmer, you will need to know how to do what's done below.

For this, you should consider using classes rather than numerically indexed arrays.  Another alternative, would be to use associative arrays.

Using associative arrays:

```
function print_event($month, $day)
{
    $events = [
        [
            "name" => "Sam",
            "month" => "1",
            "day" => "1"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "Jim",
            "month" => "2",
            "day" => "3"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "Sally",
            "month" => "3",
            "day" => "11"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "Buck",
            "month" => "4",
            "day" => "4"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "Ted",
            "month" => "12",
            "day" => "22"
        ]
    ]; // It is now clear exactly what is going on here. No need to tell me with a comment.

    foreach ($events as $event) {
        if ($month === $event["month"] && $day === $event["day"])
            return "Happy Birthday, ".$event["name"]."!";
    }
    return "No birthdays today";
}
```

The above way works pretty well, but is a quick n dirty solution.  You SHOULD use objects:

```
function print_event($month, $day) {
    $events = [
        new BirthdayEvent("Sam", "1", "1"),
        new BirthdayEvent("Jim", "2", "3"),
        new BirthdayEvent("Sally", "3", "11"),
        new BirthdayEvent("Buck", "4", "4"),
        new BirthdayEvent("Ted", "12", "22")
    ]; //It is now clear exactly what is going on here. No need to tell me with a comment.

    foreach ($events as $event) {
        if ($event->isToday($month, $day)) {
            return "Happy Birthday, " . $event->name . "!";
        }
    }
    return "No birthdays today";
}

public class BirthdayEvent {
    public function __construct($name, $month, $day){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    public function isToday($month, $day){
        return $this->month === $month && $this->day === $day;
    }
}
```

This is much better, BUT things can still improve! Right now, print event ONLY works for some events you HARDCODED, and those events are re-instantiated in memory EVERY time this funciton is called! What a disaster! This can quickly be solved simply by defining those events outside of the code, and then passing them in as a parameter, like this:

```
$events = [
    new BirthdayEvent("Sam", "1", "1"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Jim", "2", "3"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Sally", "3", "11"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Buck", "4", "4"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Ted", "12", "22")
]; //It is now clear exactly what is going on here. No need to tell me with a comment.

function print_event($events, $month, $day) {... rest of code ...}
```

Now this is getting pretty good... But it can be made even better! print_event is actually doing two things... It's both printing the event AND finding the event.  We should make find event be it's own function.

Now our code block looks like this:

```
function print_event($events, $month, $day) {
    $event = find_event($events, $month, $day);
    if($event === null)
        return "No birthdays today"; //No event was found. No birthday today
    else
        return "Happy birthday, ".$event->name."!"; //An event was found! Happy birthday!
}

function find_event($events, $month, $day) {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        if ($event->isToday($month, $day)) {
            return $event; //Yay we found an event! return it!
        }
    }
    return null; // We didn't find anything.  return null
}
```

This again is even better! If you break it down, the code is starting to kind of read like english! We've come pretty far, but this is still relatively inflexible.  Lets fix that...

```
// create our events
$events = [
    new BirthdayEvent("Sam", "1", "1"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Jim", "2", "3"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Sally", "3", "11"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Buck", "4", "4"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Ted", "12", "22")
]; //It is now clear exactly what is going on here. No need to tell me with a comment.

//This function will print the greeting from the event
function print_event(array $events, $month, $day) {
    $event = find_event($events, $month, $day);
    if($event === null)
        return "No events today"; //No event was found.
    else
        return $event->getGreeting(); //An event was found! Happy birthday!
}

//This function will find an event with a given month/day from an array of events
function find_event(array $events, $month, $day) {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        if ($event->isToday($month, $day)) {
            return $event; //Yay we found an event! return it!
        }
    }
    return null; // We didn't find anything.  return null
}

// This interface says, "Anything that implements me MUST HAVE THESE METHODS!"
interface EventInterface {
    public function isToday($month, $day);
    public function getGreeting();
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class BirthdayEvent implements EventInterface{

    protected $name;
    protected $month;
    protected $day;

    public function __construct($name, $month, $day){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    // return true if the event is today
    public function isToday($month, $day){
        return $this->month === $month && $this->day === $day;
    }

    public function getGreeting(){
        return "Happy birthday, ".$this->name."!";
    }
}

//Finally, echo the output
echo print_event($events, "3", "11");
```

We've added an interface.  This interface allows us to make multiple types of events, that all remain compatible with the print_event and find_event functions! look:

```
// This interface says, "Anything that implements me MUST HAVE THESE METHODS!"
interface EventInterface {
    public function isToday($month, $day);
    public function getGreeting();
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class BirthdayEvent implements EventInterface{

    protected $name;
    protected $month;
    protected $day;

    public function __construct($name, $month, $day){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    // return true if the event is today
    public function isToday($month, $day){
        return $this->month == $month && $this->day == $day;
    }

    public function getGreeting(){
        return "Happy birthday, ".$this->name."!";
    }
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class HolidayEvent implements EventInterface{
    protected $name;
    protected $month;
    protected $day;

    public function __construct($name, $month, $day){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    // return true if the event is today
    public function isToday($month, $day){
        return $this->month === $month && $this->day === $day;
    }

    public function getGreeting(){
        return "Happy ".$this->name."!"; //For example, it would print "Happy Columbus Day!" if it were columbus day
    }
}
```

and now our events array can look like this:

```
// create our events
$events = [
    new BirthdayEvent("Sam", "1", "1"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Jim", "2", "3"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Sally", "3", "11"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Buck", "4", "4"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Ted", "12", "22"),
    new HolidayEvent("Columbus Day", "10", "13"),
    new HolidayEvent("Labor Day", "9", "1")
]; //It is now clear exactly what is going on here. No need to tell me with a comment.
```

Now this is great and all, but there's one last thing to do... there's quite a bit of duplicate code between those two event classes! Below, we introduce an abstract class to forget about writing code twice!

```
//This is an abstract class. On it's own, it serves no purpose. But it can be extended to reduce duplicate code!
abstract class BaseEvent implements EventInterface {
    protected $name;
    protected $month;
    protected $day;

    public function __construct($name, $month, $day){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    // return true if the event is today
    public function isToday($month, $day){
        return $this->month == $month && $this->day == $day;
    }
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class BirthdayEvent extends BaseEvent {
    public function getGreeting(){
        return "Happy birthday, ".$this->name."!";
    }
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class HolidayEvent extends BaseEvent{
    public function getGreeting() {
        return "Happy ".$this->name."!"; //For example, it would print "Happy Columbus Day!" if it were columbus day
    }
}
```

This is probably overkill for what you're trying to do, but this is the best way to go about problems like this on large projects with lots of complexity.  Using this, you can now create new types of events simply like this:

```
public class SomeAwesomeNewTypeOfEvent extends BaseEvent {
    public function getGreeting() {
        return "Some awesome greeting goes here";
    }
}
```

Here's what everything will look like when it's said and done:

```
// create our events
$events = [
    new BirthdayEvent("Sam", "1", "1"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Jim", "2", "3"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Sally", "3", "11"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Buck", "4", "4"),
    new BirthdayEvent("Ted", "12", "22"),
    new HolidayEvent("Columbus Day", "10", "13"),
    new HolidayEvent("Labor Day", "9", "1")
]; //It is now clear exactly what is going on here. No need to tell me with a comment.

//This function will print the greeting from the event
function print_event(array $events, $month, $day) {
    $event = find_event($events, $month, $day);
    if($event === null)
        return "No events today"; //No event was found.
    else
        return $event->getGreeting(); //An event was found! Happy birthday!
}

//This function will find an event with a given month/day from an array of events
function find_event(array $events, $month, $day) {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        if ($event->isToday($month, $day)) {
            return $event; //Yay we found an event! return it!
        }
    }
    return null; // We didn't find anything.  return null
}

// This interface says, "Anything that implements me MUST HAVE THESE METHODS!"
interface EventInterface {
    public function isToday($month, $day);
    public function getGreeting();
}

//This is an abstract class. On it's own, it serves no purpose. But it can be extended to reduce duplicate code!
abstract class BaseEvent implements EventInterface {
    protected $name;
    protected $month;
    protected $day;

    public function __construct($name, $month, $day){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    // return true if the event is today
    public function isToday($month, $day){
        return $this->month == $month && $this->day == $day;
    }
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class BirthdayEvent extends BaseEvent {
    public function getGreeting(){
        return "Happy birthday, ".$this->name."!";
    }
}

// This class implements event by defining the methods in the Event interface
public class HolidayEvent extends BaseEvent{
    public function getGreeting(){
        return "Happy ".$this->name."!"; //For example, it would print "Happy Columbus Day!" if it were columbus day
    }
}

//Finally, echo the output
echo print_event($events, "3", "11");
```

Let me know if you want me to explain anything.